# How do I use Clap to parse filenames?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, clap

I got this:

```
let args: Vec::<String> = std::env::args().collect();
let matches = App::new("Rust grader")
                    .author("Arkadiusz Bulski <arek.bulski@gmail.com>")
                    .arg(Arg::with_name("noprofile")
                            .long("noprofile")
                            .takes_value(false)
                            .help("Disable profiling, save time"))
                    .get_matches();
let config = matches.value_of("noprofile");
```

And a usage:  `./binary-runner --noprofile -- tsp-arekbulski-*.rs`

How can I get this clap app to recognize filenames?

Error:

```
error: Found argument 'tsp-arekbulski-01-trivial.rs' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
    binary-runner --noprofile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```
let matches = App::new("Rust runner")
                    .author("Arkadiusz Bulski <arek.bulski@gmail.com>")
                    .arg(Arg::with_name("sources")
                            .multiple(true)
                            .help("Use this to pass argfilenames"))
                    .get_matches();
```